# Crash when Kotlin Coroutine Not Complete in Android App

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I am using Hilt dependency injection to retrieve data from a Firestore Database. I have a getResources coroutine which is called when by the init in my viewModel. In my view, I attempt to get the first x elements of the populated data. However, the app crashes with this error.

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Empty list doesn't contain element at index 0.
        at kotlin.collections.EmptyList.get(Collections.kt:36)
        at kotlin.collections.EmptyList.get(Collections.kt:24)
```

I am guessing that the data load from Firestore has not completed, so when I try and get resources[i], it's empty and it crashes. This happens even when I do a null check. I cannot init{} without a coroutine and if I try and use a suspend function it doesn't like it either. How do I make the view wait until the viewmodel has the loaded data?

ViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class ResourcesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: ResourcesRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    val data: MutableState<DataOrException<List<Resource>, Exception>> = mutableStateOf(
        DataOrException(
            listOf(),
            Exception("")
        )
    )

    init {
        getResources()
    }

    private fun getResources() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            Log.d("getting resources", "currently getting resources")
            data.value = repository.getResourcesFromFireStore()
            Log.d("complete","complete")
        }
    }
}
```

ResourcesRepository.kt

```
@Singleton
class ResourcesRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val db: FirebaseFirestore
) {
    val resources = ArrayList<Resource>()
    suspend fun getResourcesFromFireStore(): DataOrException<List<Resource>, Exception> {
        val resourcesRef: CollectionReference = db.collection("updated-resources-new")
        val dataOrException = DataOrException<List<Resource>, Exception>()
        try {
            dataOrException.data = resourcesRef.get().await().map { document ->
                document.toObject(Resource::class.java)
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "${dataOrException.data}")
        } catch (e: FirebaseFirestoreException) {
            dataOrException.e = e
        }
```

View.kt

```
@Composable
fun ResourcesScreenContent(viewModel: ResourcesViewModel) {
    LazyColumn (
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 10.dp, vertical = 20.dp)
    ) {
        val resources : List<Resource>? = viewModel.data.value.data
        items(30) {
            for (i in 0 ..30) {
                ExpandableCard(resource = resources!![i])
                Divider(thickness = 20.dp, color = Color.White)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Since it is a `State`, why not check beforehand if the list is `null` or `empty` & also check if the amount of data is available i.e. 30 item count?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also add the content of your `Resource` class. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

you're doing one minor mistake, in **forloop you are using 0...30** so it will run 30 times irrespective of resources list size. so in for loop you have to pass *resources.count*

```
@Composable
fun ResourcesScreenContent(viewModel: ResourcesViewModel) {
    LazyColumn (
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 10.dp, vertical =  20.dp)
    ) {
        val resources : List<Resource>? = viewModel.data.value.data
        items(resources.count) { i ->
           
               ExpandableCard(resource = resources!![i])
               Divider(thickness = 20.dp, color = Color.White)
        
        }
    }
}
```

**Hope it is clear my brother**